# Redirect page from script in a frame

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am loading a page every 4th second (lobby_box.php) using javascript. This page is being loaded in a div on my (index.php) page. The problem is that (lobby_box.php) contains a code that should redirect the client from index.php > anotherpage.php. But it redirects the client to (anotherpage.php) inside the div that loads the (lobby_box.php) every 4th second.

So basically, it doesn't redirect the whole page, just the inside the div.

I have tried using everything I can get my hands on. I've been trying to redirect using javascript, jquery, php codes but it still only redirects inside the div.

```
function getLobbyBox() { 
    var http; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 

    http.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
        if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200) 
        { 
            document.getElementById("lobby_new_content").innerHTML= http.responseText; 
        } 
    }   

    http.open("GET", "includes/lobby_box.php?noCache=" + Math.random(), true); 
    http.send(); 
}
```

This is the function that loads (lobby_box.php) every 4th second.

This is the code that should redirect to anotherpage.php but only redirects to it inside the div.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($game) > 0) {
 echo '<script>window.location.href = "/anotherpage.php";</script>';
 exit();
}
```

I've also tried

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($game) > 0) {
 header('location: anotherpage.php');
 exit();
}
```

Is it even possible to solve it like that? Or do I need to find another way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pages, both the parent and the one in the iframe, are on the same domain, you can easily call `window.parent` from the frame and redirect that way.

```
window.parent.location.href = '/whatever-page';
```

Comment: I also tried window.top. Doesn't seem to work anyways.

Comment: Is there any error shown in the console, or is `window.parent.location` still only redirecting inside the iframe?

Comment: It doesn't redirect inside the frame either. No errors is shown.

Comment: Did you add it into the 0 row check? Along the lines of: `if(mysqli_num_rows($game) > 0) {
 echo '<script>window.parent.location.href = "/anotherpage.php";</script>';
 exit();
}`
Definitely a strange one if that's not working and both your scripts are local.

Comment: Solved it, check answer above.

Comment: Ah, no worries - I guess the confusion came from 'frame', but not 'iframe' :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Probably since it's not really a frame, but content loaded in a div using XMLHttpRequest. The working code was.

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/anotherpage.php" target="_new">
```

I just put that inside an echo inside my if statement.